# LINQ Growth Chart

Tags: c#, linq

I'm getting sick with this problem. I have some tables that have contentes launched in a specific date to a region.
I'm making an MVC app and it will show a chart of grow by date.

I'm trying to make a method that recieves int days and count each day the amount of contents launched til that day. Example:

**Region en-US**

- Content X - Date 12/03/2010
- Content Y - Date 12/03/2010
- Content Z - Date 13/03/2010

**Region pt-BR**

- Content A - Date 13/03/2010
- Content B - Date 14/03/2010

**Region ja-JP**

- Content J - Date 15/03/2010

So the chart must show:

**Date 12/03/2010:**

- en-US: 2
- pt-BR: 0
- ja-JP: 0

**Date 13/03/2010**

- en-US: 1
- pt-BR: 1
- ja-JP: 0

**Date 14/03/2010**

- en-US: 0
- pt-BR: 1
- ja-JP: 0

**Date 15/03/2010**

- en-US: 0
- pt-BR: 0
- ja-JP: 1

I feel powerless trying to make this query.

Anyone can help?

Here, other method I've created to show day-by-day numbers per Country:

```
public KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>>[] ChartDayByDay(int days, string locale)
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>>[] contagens;

        DateTime inicio = DateTime.Today.AddDays(days * (-1));

        var qry = from c in db.XBLRegionalInfos
                  where c.PublishDate != null
                  && c.PublishDate > inicio
                  select c;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale))
            qry = qry.Where(x => x.RegionId == locale);

        var qry2 = (from c in qry
                    group c by c.RegionId into g
                    let count = g.Count()
                    where count > 0
                    select g).ToList();

        var regioes = db.XBLRegions.ToList();

        contagens = new KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>>[qry2.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < qry2.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < qry2[i].Count(); j++)
            {
                var pais = qry2[i].ElementAt(j).Region.Country;

                contagens[i] = new KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>>(
                    pais, CountPeriod(days, qry2[i].ElementAt(j).RegionId));
            }
        }

        return contagens;
    }
```

Comment: Not very clear what you are trying to do or how your data is structured. Can you please explain in more detail? Are you trying to improve the pasted code - does it do what you need? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with linq to objects at least:

```
public KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>>[] ChartDayByDay(int days, string locale)
{
    return db
        .XBLRegionalInfos
        .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(locale) || x.RegionId == locale)
        .Where(x => x.PublishDate > DateTime.Today.AddDays(days * (-1)))
        .GroupBy(x => new {x.PublishDate.Date, x.RegionId})
        .Select(x => new {x.Key, Count = x.Count()})
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key.Date)
        .Select(x =>
                new KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>>(
                    x.Key.ToString(),
                    x.Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(y.Key.RegionId, y.Count)).ToList()))
        .ToArray();
}
```